# Sonarqube and postgresql when run with docker-compose don't honor the username and password on the sonar Dashboard

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sonarqube

[image]I want to setup sonarqube with postgresql through docker-compose and though I provide environment variables in the docker-compose.yml they don't get honored by Sonarqube. I am not able to login to the Sonarqube dashboard with the provided username and password in the docker-compose.yml.

My docker-compose.yml looks like below:-

```
  sonarkube:
    container_name: sonarkube
    image: sonarqube:latest
    restart: on-failure:5
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "
        while ! nc -z sonar_postgres 5432;
        do
          echo sleeping;
          sleep 1;
        done;
        echo Connected!;
      "
    command: -Dsonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xms512m
    command: -Dsonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx2048m
    command: -Dsonar.sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xms512m
    command: -Dsonar.sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx2048m
    command: -Dsonar.login=biplab
    command: -Dsonar.password=biplab
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - sonar_postgres
    environment:
      - Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://sonar_postgres:5432/sonar?user=biplab&password=biplab
      - Dsonar.jdbc.username=biplab
      - Dsonar.jdbc.password=biplab
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=biplab
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=biplab
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://sonar_postgres:5432/sonar?user=biplab&password=biplab
      - SONAR_LOGIN=biplab
      - SONAR_PASSWORD=biplab
    volumes:
      - /opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - ./data/sonarqube/docker:/opt/sonarqube/docker
    networks:
      - frontend

  sonar_postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    restart: on-failure:5
    hostname: sonar_postgres
    container_name: sonar_postgres
    networks:
      - frontend
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=biplab
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=biplab
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:z
      - /opt/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z

volumes:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:

networks:
  frontend:
```

Comment: Did you investigate the SonarQube log files?

Comment: Hey @JeroenHeier, I looked at the PostGreSQL DB after it was created through the yml file and i could log in to the database with "pqsl -U biplab -w biplab -d biplab". Also sonarqube logs don't show any errors. I am not able to login to the sonar Dashboard still!!

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose.yaml is not valid:
1. Multiple `command` definition
2. Wrong env var POSTGRESQL_DATABASE, should be POSTGRES_DB

This docker-compose.yaml file works well and is able to login:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions

  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
      - POSTGRES_DB=sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  sonarnet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

Comment: The above doesn't work. after using your docker-compose.yml I am getting the same error as "Authentication failed". @AlexPliutau

Comment: @BiplabBiswas please show a screenshot or log why it doesn't

Comment: I used a bitnami sonar docker image and I was able to make login with my custom username and password. Thanks you guys for all the help!! Really appreciate it.